# Why is it a requirement that we follow the central path in the interior point method?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

I have been studying some of the interior point methods recently, and there is one in particular that I find most intuitive:  The *path-following* method method.  In this method, we put the inequality constraints into the objective function, and vary $\mu$ from $\infty$ to $0$.  This variation allows us to follow what is called the "central path".

But from my point of view any variation in $\mu$ towards 0 will allow us to reach the optimum eventually.  So, why is it si important that we follow the special "central path" instead of just following some other route to the optimum?

EDIT: it is maybe true that I am missing understanding some of the properties of the central path.  Some of the properties are covered here on slide 21: https://web.stanford.edu/class/msande310/lecture11.pdf.   If someone can understand these better than me, then maybe I can see why following the central path is so important here.

**SECOND EDIT**:  I am talking about $\mu$ in the sense of a modified objective function (usually called a barrier objective function) like this: $b^Ty+\mu\Sigma log(x_j)$   s.t.   $x_j \ge 0$.   Just as it shows in the link I posted.

Related question that might benefit from this: [primal-dual interior-point method picking value of $\mu$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2226459/primal-dual-interior-point-method-picking-value-of-mu?rq=1)

Comment: By varying $\mu$ you, by definition, follow the central path, because it is simply *defined* as the curve of optimal points obtained for all $\mu$.

Comment: yes, @Alex I understand that.  But why not set $\mu$ to something very small, and optimize that instead of varying $\mu$?  It should get you to the optimum faster, right?  Why does we needs to follow the central path? Thanks.

Comment: Numerical reasons only. If you had infinite precision arithmetic as fast as floating point arithmetic, you could have done it in "one take" by choosing a tiny $\mu$ from the very beginning.

Comment: I don't exactly follow you...can you post an answer pls @Alex?

Comment: @Alex even in exact arithmetic it is generally better to follow the central path than to pick a single, small $\mu$. That's because if you start from very small $\mu$, it is very likely that you are "far" from the optimum solution, and Newton's method takes quite a few iterations to get to the region of quadratic convergence. On the other hand, the larger values of $\mu$ tend to get you to quadratic convergence sooner---and then if you reduce $\mu$ in a controlled fashion, you *stay* in this high-performance region.

Comment: On the other hand, there's a tradeoff here, because you could reduce $\mu$ _too_ slowly, and then you get lousy performance that way, too. Constructing the best strategy for selecting and reducing $\mu$ is pretty much the primary challenge of all _practical_ interior-point method construction and even much theoretical study.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I think you have it backwards - assuming that we have an objective function like this $G_u = c'x - \mu*\Sigma log(x_i)$, then a _larger_ value of $\mu$ would mean you are probably far from the optimum solution because you are far from the boundary.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what I'm saying. With small $\mu$, the central path is close to the boundary, yes. But it's very likely that you are far *from the solution to the barrier objective*---in terms of the number of iterations required to actually reach it---if you start from an arbitrary feasible point. It is easier to solve the barrier objective for large $\mu$.

Comment: I see @MichaelGrant, thank you.  Because with a small $\mu$ there is very little incentive to obey the inequality constraints.  So, if we start with a small $\mu$, then we will probably not obey those constraints and hence be "very far from the solution to the barrier objective".

Comment: scratch that previous comment - I was just plain wrong.  What I really mean is, with a small $\mu$, you will be closer to the boundary, but not necessarily closer to the minimizer of the objective function.  But with a large $\mu$ you are sort of in the center of the feasible region, so it will require fewer iterations in order to converge on a solution.  This is actually very similar to choosing a starting point in the ellipsoid method.  A starting point near the boundary just results in many small ellipses and the algorithm progresses very slowly.

Answer (score 3):

Let us look at a small example:
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \min_x & \quad c^T x \\
    \text{s.t.} &\quad e^T x \leq 1 \\
                &\quad x_i \geq 0
\end{aligned}
$$
where $e = (1, \dots, 1)^T$ and $c$ is some arbitrary vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Now, let us look at the very simple case of a *primal* interior point method. The reason I am simplifying everything is because I want to demonstrate a point.

For a given $\mu$, the objective is to minimize
$$
f(x) = c^T x - \frac{1}{\mu} \log(1 - \mathrm{e}^T x ) - \frac{1}{\mu}\sum_{i=1}^n \log(-x_i) 
$$

Let us see how this functions is minimized with Newton's method. The negative gradient is 
$$\nabla f(x) = \frac{1}{\mu} \underbrace{\left[ \mu c - \frac{1}{(1 - e^T x)} e - \left(\frac{1}{x_1}, \dots, \frac{1}{x_n}\right)^T \right]}_{g(x)}$$
The Hessian is
$$
\nabla^2 f(x) = \frac{1}{\mu} \underbrace{\left[\frac{1}{\mu(1 - e^T x)^2} e e^T + \operatorname{diag}\left(\frac{1}{x_1^2}, \dots, \frac{1}{x_n^2}\right)
 \right]}_{H(x)}
$$
In each iteration of Newton's method, we find the descent direction $d$ by solving the system
$$
\nabla^2 f(x) d = -\nabla f(x)
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
H(x) d = -g(x)
$$

Let us analyze some phenomena.

- Case 1: $x$ is close to the boundary of the feasible set, and $\mu$ is moderate. In that case, some of the values $\{1 - e^T x, x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ are close to zero, while others are not. Thus, the matrix $H(x)$ becomes very ill-conditioned, and, in addition, some of the entries of $g(x)$ might be very small while others are very large. Both phenomena destroy any hope of accurately solving the Newton system.
- Case 2: $x$ is far from the boundary of the feasible set, and $\mu$ is large. In that case, all of the values in the set $\{1 - e^T x, x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ are far away from zero, but the entries of $\mu c$ are very large. Thus, when computing $g(x)$ we add numbers of different orders of magnitude, causing serious round off errors. The same phenomena happen when computing $H(x)$. Thus, both $g(x)$ and $H(x)$ are inaccurate, and therefore our Newton direction $d$ is inaccurate.
- Case 3: $x$ is far to the boundary, and $\mu$ is moderate. In that case, for the same reasoning above, both $g(x)$ and $H(x)$ are computed quite accurately, without entries of substantially different orders of magnitude. In addition $H(x)$ is not ill-conditioned, and we can find $d$ quite accurately.
- Case 4: $x$ is close to the boundary, and $\mu$ is very large.The entries of $\mu c$ are become very large, some of the values in $\{1 - e^T x, x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ are close to zero while others are not. Thus, it seems that we are, again, adding numbers of different orders of magnitude. However, in this case it works in our favor, since near the boundary we should follow a direction that is similar to $c$, and thus making the rest of the terms when computing $g(x)$ negligible is not bad. The matrix $H(x)$ can be ill-conditioned and inaccurately computed. However, looking closer we observe that $g(x)$ is a sum of $\mu c$ and the dominant Eigenvectors of $H(x)$, and thus the Newton system is solved quite accurately.

Following the central path ensures that we always fall in cases 3 and 4.

Comment: I'd say this is pretty good, but I don't agree with your analysis of Case 2. Adding numbers of greatly different magnitudes does not introduce serious roundoff errors. Consider, for instance, $1+10^{-10]$. Even if our precision is low enough that we arrive at the result $1$---we have completely lost the second term---we still have a relative accuracy of $10^{-10}$, which is plenty adequate. The problems we encounter in numerical solutions are really not _roundoff_ errors but _cancellation_ errors: when two numbers of _approximately the same magnitude_ are subtracted.

Comment: I am confused about the precision here as well...[this](http://www.drdobbs.com/floating-point-summation/184403224) resource seems to also think that precision is lost when adding two numbers of different magnitude.  Thank you guys for your continued attention to this question.

Comment: @Alex one more question for you:  You say we follow the central path for “numerical reasons only”.  I am surprised, because the central path also guarantees that we are dual feasible.  Your answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2310121/why-do-we-need-to-check-both-primal-and-dual-feasibility-in-lp-programs?rq=1) you say that we have to stay dual feasible “knowing when to stop”.  I thought we would be following the central path in order to remain dual feasible for the reasons mentioned in this other question.

Comment: So, which one is it:  1) we follow the central path to guarantee that we are dual feasible to guarantee that we can know when to stop.  OR 2)  We guarantee that we are dual feasible in order to follow the central path, to guarantee that we do not run into numerical issues.  which one?

Comment: @MichaelGrant, precision is lost when adding numbers of different magnitude, because the first thing the computer does is it lines up the exponents. This resource explains it nicely. http://www.sce.carleton.ca/faculty/chinneck/po/Chapter7.pdf

Comment: Not in a relative sense. That requires cancellation.

Comment: Ah, I see the section about scaling. Yes, that is definitely relevant to recovering the values of a problem expressed in natural units. But it doesn't affect the precision with which the algorithm operates.

Comment: Seems that @MichaelGrant is correct, and my analysis of the source of error is incorrect. He is also correct in saying that following the central path ensures that we stay close to the region of convergence of Newton's method, thus increasing the speed of the algorithm.

Comment: @jaja Regarding 'knowing when to stop', when you solve a sub-problem for a specific $\mu$, you have a guaranteed duality gap. Thus, your 'when top stop' translates directly to 'what value of $\mu$ we want to reach'

Comment: @MichaelGrant you're basically saying taking larger steps in the beginning (i.e. having a large $\mu$) will get us into the region of quadratic convergence faster than sticking with a small value of $\mu$.  Thanks.