# Chicken or egg problem: Which comes first duality or numerical precision in following the central path in LP?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

In the interior point method, the path-following version follows the "central path", which is the path that minimizes the Barrier function in a minimization problem $B(x,u) = c^T\cdot x - \mu \cdot \Sigma \log(c_i(x))$ at every value of $\mu$ while varying $\mu$ from $\mu=\infty$ to $\mu=0$.  And, I have heard that we follow the central path for different reasons, so I'd like to know what is the real reason.

I have heard from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2335229/why-is-it-a-requirement-that-we-follow-the-central-path-in-the-interior-point-me) source that we follow the central path for "numerical reasons *ONLY*".  Because if we vary $\mu$ in a different way, then we would suffer from lack of numerical precision. Because we could be adding numbers of very different orders of magnitude, which is numerically unstable when using floating point precision.

But, there's something else that the central path gives us that I'm surprised is not the reason we follow it -> dual feasibility.  If we maintain dual feasibility, then we can know how close we are to the optimal value by using the duality gap ($c^Tx - b^Ty$).  Here is a resource that agrees with that: [Why do we need to check both primal and dual feasibility in LP programs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2310121/why-do-we-need-to-check-both-primal-and-dual-feasibility-in-lp-programs?rq=1)

Do we follow the central path for numerical reasons ONLY, or do we follow it because it guarantees us dual feasibility for our stopping conditions?

Comment: In the previous question, the choices were 1) select a single, small value of $\mu$ that guarantees a sufficiently accurate solution, and minimize  $B(x,\mu)$ for that single value; or 2) start at a larger $\mu$ and "follow" the central path down to that small $\mu$. The answer is 2, because of performance reasons. But note: in the end, you *still* have a solution to the barrier problem for small $\mu$. The end result is the same either way.

Comment: yes i understand that @MichaelGrant.  So you seem to be saying that these two things are **not** mutually exclusive:  following the central path, and dual feasibility.  One can vary $\mu$ by some other mechanism, and thus not follow the central path and still maintain dual feasibility, and thus still know "when to stop"?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm saying. Now, for very general nonlinear problems, recovering the dual feasible point may be useful to construct a more accurate stopping criterion. But you're still not going to need to bother with that until you're at the final value of $\mu$, which you can select in advance of that.